# Send incomming text from one com port out another

Tags: batch-file, serial-port

I just need what I hope is a little help re-directing the text coming into `COM5` to be sent out on `COM3`.

I have an android phone which sends GPS NMEA data to my laptop. This shows up on `COM5` in Device Manager.

I have a serial device *(computerized astronomy telescope mount)* which needs the NMEA data stream at power up. This is attached through a USB to Serial dongle showing up on `COM3`.

Both connections are working.

The only thing I need is a way of passing the incoming GPS data to the mount through its `COM` port.

Comment: If you already have two programs that work with each other, you will have to either incorporate the other function into one program or create a third program that has both functions. However, it will not be possible with batch files.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need to put a PC in the middle to forward the NMEA commands and not connect both serial devices directly.

I guess you have your reasons; whatever those are you can do that very easily with Termite:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56377015/11476836

Comment: Marcos, I removed some bloat from the question body itself, so as you stated, 'they'll have their reasons', I thought I'd add that information here. "I have an App on the laptop that uses the GPS data and it's coming through just fine. I have another app that controls the mount through the USB Serial connection that also is working". I would suggest therefore that the PC is required for those two apps to function.

Comment: Exactly right , Compo.  Il'll give Termite a try tonight.  It's getting flagged as spyware by IT here at work. - Pat

Comment: OK then guys, I see your point. There is a similar use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062146/11476836)